# HTML Class won't get the style from CSS

Tags: html, css

It might be really stupid and easy, but I spend two hours trying to get it.
I have a simple div with a class "payment"

```
<div class="payment">

</div>
```

and in css

```
.payment  {
  height: 289px;
  width: 320px;
  background-image: url('../images/pay/sprite_paywall.png');
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute; }
```

I checked the css file on the network, and saw the class there. I tried to delete the cache browser, but no luck. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Did you check with "Inspect Element" in your browser?

Comment: Can we see a fiddle? Try setting background: red. It looks like it can't load the image, or you didn't include the css file properly

Comment: If you use chrome or firefox, you can right click on the DIV and go to inspectElement to view what CSS is being applied and whether it's being overridden.

Comment: Can't see a problem with the CSS itself so it's either not being implemented properly or something else is interfering with it

Comment: How you check your image path ?

Comment: @Remy yes I did, but it doesn't take the class payment from the css.

Comment: If you remove the positioning does it appear?

Comment: @Aliassse nope. It tried to add style directly in dom, and it works. It only won't take class from css

Comment: Check CSS path, Image path and check for double class.

Comment: @mdesdev I did check CSS path, Image path and if there is double class. I changed the class name several times. still doesn't work

Comment: The problem likely comes from somewhere else. [validate](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) your CSS.

Comment: @catwoman Strange if it works with inline CSS...is everything else works ok?

Comment: Do you have more than 1 CSS file? It could be that one is overwriting the other? Try adding !important

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like this : [**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/zFWHX/2/)

```
 background: #f00 url('../images/pay/sprite_paywall.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
```

Instead of background image, im using background color. you are not specifying any left, top etc.. so there is no need to specify **position**.

Comment: She can be using `position:absolute` for other purposes, so it is correct there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the import of the CSS file to you'r html code. You have to ways to do that(always add the tags in head tag).

1- Using `<link>` tag like that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your/css/route_file.css" />
```

2- Using `<style>` that not requieres to import a file:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .payment  {
        height: 289px;
        width: 320px;
        background-image: url('../images/pay/sprite_paywall.png');
        background-position: 0 0;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: absolute; 
    }
</style>
```